# Latest Kubuntu update for MySQL seems to have broken Akonadi

Tags: mysql, akonadi, korganizer

I'm currently running Kubuntu 14.04 and just installed the update to MySQL through Muon Update manager.  I believe there were 4 files involved taking the version to 5.5.53.  The issue I have is that now KOrganizer calender will not load saying `Akonadi personal information management service is not operational.`

The main error I get is:

```
Akonadi control process not registered at D-Bus.
Details: The Akonadi control process is not registered at D-Bus which typically means it was not started or encountered a fatal error during startup.
```

I've got same error but using a system backup and reverting to mysql 5.5.52 it all worked OK again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql-files
```

solved the problem after the update to 5.5.53. Albeit no files will be written to this new directory.